# Compute the $n$-fold iteration of an indefinite integral operator using integration by parts and induction.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the following integral operator $T:L^2([0,2])\longrightarrow L^{2}([0,2])$ defined by $$(Tf)(x)=\int_0^x f(y)\,dy.$$ Page 230 of Peter Lax's functional analysis claimed that the $n$-fold iterate of $T$ is given by the formula: $$(T^n f)(x)=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x (x-r)^{n-1}f(r) \, dr, \text{ for } x\in [0,1].$$ And he said that this can be proved using induction and integration by parts.

---

So I followed his instruction:  Suppose this holds for a fixed $n$, and we prove it is true for $n+1$. By definition, for $x\in [0,1]$,
\begin{align*}
& (T^{n+1}f)(x)=T((T^{n}f)(x))=\int_0^x (T^{n}f)(y) \, dy \\[8pt]
= {} &\int_0^x \Big(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^y(y-r)^{n-1}f(r) \, dr\Big) \, dy\\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x \int_0^y (y-r)^{n-1}f(r) \,dr\,dy.
\end{align*}

For fixed $y\in [0,1]$, we deal with the inner integral $\int_0^y (y-r)^{n-1} f(r) \, dr$.  Consider $u:=f(r)$ so that $du=f'(r) \, dr$, and $dv:=(y-r)^{n-1} \, dr$ so that $v=-\frac{1}{n}(y-r)^{n}.$ Then, using integration by parts, we have $$\int_{0}^{y}(y-r)^{n-1}f(r) \, dr=-\frac{1}{n}(y-r)^n f(r)+\int_0^1\frac{1}{n}(y-r)^n f'(r) \, dr.$$

Then, I focused on $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 (y-r)^{n}f'(r) \, dr$. Consider $dv:=f'(r)\,dr$ so that $f(r)=v$, and $u:=(y-r)^{n}$ so that $du=-n(y-r)^{n-1} \, dr.$ Using integration by parts, we have $$\dfrac{1}{n} \int_0^1 (y-r)^{n}f'(r) \, dr = \frac{1}{n}(y-r)^n f(r)+\frac{1}{n}\cdot n\int_0^1 (y-r)^{n-1} \, dr.$$ So if we plug this back into above, it seems I just proved $0=0$.

What should I do? Did I even have a wrong start? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in principle you don't know that $f$ is differentiable. This is probably not a big deal, as differentiable functions are dense. But it complicates the proof.

In your use of integration by parts, if you do integration by parts twice while exchanging the roles of the two functions, so indeed you get nothing.

Here the argument becomes much easier if instead you do the following (where the exchange of integrals is valid due to Fubini); no parts, tough.
\begin{align}
T^{n+1}f(x)
&=T^n(Tf)x
=\frac1{(n-1)!}\,\int_0^x(x-r)^{n-1}\,Tf(r)\,dr\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{(n-1)!}\,\int_0^x(x-r)^{n-1}\,\int_0^rf(s)\,ds\,dr\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{(n-1)!}\,\int_0^rf(s)\,\int_s^x(x-r)^{n-1}\,dr\,ds\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{(n-1)!}\,\int_0^rf(s)\,\frac{(x-s)^n}n\,ds\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{n!}\,\int_0^rf(s)\,(x-s)^n\,ds\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

Comment: Nice solution! Yeah I am also wondering if f can be differentiable. Really a nice answer. Thank you!